# multithread debugging from immediate window

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, debugging, immediate-window

When I break into the debugger and call a function from the immediate window of VS2010 on the main thread, the function gets executed normally on the same thread. However, it appears *other* threads are not executed during that time of evaluation, as long as they are in a sleeping state. Can this behavior be confirmed by someone? It seems to be, the interthread communication via the Windows API does not properly work in that context?

Since this potentially makes the evaluations hang in a multithreaded scenario, any workarounds are also highly appreciated.

Edit: the problem seems to be more general. Immediate window obviously - in contrast to step-by-step debugging - does only execute the main/current thread. I was not able to find any official list on the restrictions by now. So if somebody can help with that, would be great as well...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same problem. It appears to be intended. Or [at least documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171381(v=vs.100).aspx).

I wonder, why not more people realized this problem.